# How to create a link to a folder in Ubuntu 18.04 using GUI

Tags: shortcuts, filemanager

If my memory is not playing me up this could be done with old versions of Ubuntu but I can't find a way of doing it with 18.04.

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 21):

## Drag the folder while holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> button

You will see a "link" under the dragging hand badge while the folder is dragged as shown in the picture below.

[image]

If you drag the folder you want to link to, to a different folder, then the link will have the same name as the linked folder. The linked folder will have a black link arrow to show that it is a link.

If you create a link of a folder within the same parent folder the link will be called `Link to <Name of Folder>`.

[image]

## Alternately <kbd>Alt</kbd> Drag

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag-and-drop a little menu with copy, move, link, and cancel appears:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @PerlDuck I have added this method to my answer.

Comment: And finally convert the link from absolute to relative by clicking  Right-click-scripts-myscript(http://papou.epizy.com/notes/symbolic_link/)

Answer (score 6):

You have to enable the menu entry in the file manager:

- Just open `file manager/files/preferences`
- Go to Tab `behaviour/Link Creation` -> `Show action to create symbolic links`

Comment: Thank you. I cannot get why at all this was removed from default settings.

Comment: link always found broken when restart.I followed this method, then created a link of my internal file and pasted it in desktop.When I restart the machine ,the link is already broken and doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Just right-click on the folder, then select **Create Link** from the menu.

Comment: This is only possible if the checkbox "Show action to create symbolic links" in the preferences is ticked. See [Mr. Schulze's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092892/504066).

Comment: @PerlDuck ah, I see. Mine was already checked on :-)

Comment: And finally convert the link from absolute to relative by clicking  Right-click-scripts-myscript (http://papou.epizy.com/notes/symbolic_link/)