# How to create a symbolic link to certain files within a directory?

Tags: symbolic-link

I want to create a symbolic link from `Dir1`, but only for certain files. Let's say I have these files within `Dir1`:

```
file_1.a
file_2.a
file_2.a.b
```

Now I want to create a symbolic link, but only to those `*.a` files for which  a `*.a.b` file exists. So in the end it should be a symbolic link only to `file_2.a` (for this example - I will have few thousands files like this). How should I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a link to a folder in Ubuntu 18.04 using GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092879/how-to-create-a-link-to-a-folder-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-gui)

Comment: @mook765 you're right, it should be either a link to `file_2.a` OR a link to `Dir2` containing `file_2.a`. Whatever is easiest

Comment: @mook765 The link should be created in another directory

Comment: It is still not clear. Do you want to create symbolic links for any file that ends in `.a` or any files that has `.a` in its name (including `file_2.a.b`). You say "*So in the end it should be a symbolic link only to `file_2.a`*". But any file that includes `.a` will include `file_1.a` too. So, the "only to `file_2.a` is not true. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Add this information to your question.